# Mysql : how to use if /elseif

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Check table if a certain value available update it , and insert it if not available .
For example :
if the date of today are available just update employee name , but if there is row for today insert it .

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: use loop in mysql with IF AND ELSE conditions

Comment: have you tried anything in code

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HI First use SELECT query to find record which you want to update or insert exists in your table use mysql_num_rows() to find it,

 Then use if else statement 

    if($numrows != '')
     {
      echo "your update query here";
      }
     else {
       echo "your insert query here";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `date` column has a unique key on it, then

```sql
INSERT INTO employees (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = ...;
```

Which will try to insert the row, but if such a date already exist, it will hit a duplicate key, in which case it will just update the name for the row which had the duplicate key.

(Let me emphasize: for this to work, you need to have a unique key on the `date` column)

For more details see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Also, `REPLACE` is another solution which might work in your case: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

With `REPLACE` you just run

```sql
REPLACE INTO employees (...) VALUES (...);
```

As if you were running an `INSERT`. The way it works is it tries to `INSERT` the row, and if it cannot because of a duplicate key, it replaces the entire row that conflicts with the values you provide.